# Geoserver, WFS-T and versioning

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

It seems there used to be a GeoServer extension to support "Versioned Web Feature Services" (https://github.com/boundlessgeo/geoserver-2.1.x/tree/master/extension/wfsv).

Interestingly I can find no information about a versioning extension to the WFS standard, or about this GeoServer extension online.

So using GeoServer 2.13+, how do folks implement versioning or at least an audit log for WFS-T transactions? For example how do you track changes to a dataset maintained by multiple members of a team? This could then lead into publishing workflows etc, but I'm trying to wrap my head around how to implement a versioning workflow first ..

Comment: I worked on the Versioning WFS extension many years ago (12+?). It is now retired, geogig is providing somewhat similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [geogig](http://geogig.org/) or there are various ways to add logging to PostGIS databases (and probably more expensive DBs too) that might fulfil a simpler audit function.